# "The view page.views.register_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." Error while using custom registration form

Tags: django, authentication

I'm trying to create a custom user registration page only with email and password. This is my
view.py file:

```
def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user =request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponse(f"You are already authenticated as {user.email}.")
    context = {}

    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email').lower()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            destination = kwargs.get("next")
            if destination:
                return redirect(destination)
            return redirect("home") 
        else: 
            context['registration_form'] = form

        return render(request, 'page/templates/register.html', context)
```

When I try to access to the register.html page using the link in my website this is the error I'm gettin.

```
The view page.views.register_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

What could be the problem?  Thank you

Comment: Reduce the indentation of the last `return render` so that it is _outside_ the `if request.POST:` block. Also `if request.POST:` (It may work here but a POST request does not necessarily need to have any content) is not the correct way to test for a post request use `if request.method == 'POST':` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my problem with your help!

Answer (score 0):

in your view, you are handling only POST method, what about GET method ? can you show us your html content ? make sure that you are setting the method="POST"